# Which matrix belongs to the stabiliser of a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

We consider the action of $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ on the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ by linear transformation. Which of these matrices belong to the stabiliser of the vector $\begin{pmatrix} 1\\3\end{pmatrix}$?

**A:** $\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1  \\ 4 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$

**B:** $\begin{pmatrix} 3 & -1  \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$

**C:** $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0  \\ -3 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$

**D:** $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0  \\ 0 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$

**What I have tried so far:**

Given a group action of a group $G$ on a set $X$. For $x \in X$, the stabiliser of $x$, denoted $\text{Stab}(x)$ is such that $g \cdot x=x $. Hence I think it is **D** Since $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0  \\ 0 & 3 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1\\3\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 1\\3\end{pmatrix}$

Is this method correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you miscalculated the value of
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0  \\ 0 & 3 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1\\3\end{pmatrix}$$
But if $g \in G_x$, then $g \cdot x = x$. So your method is correct but there is an error in your calculation.